# why the store reset data when write window.location.replace("/home");

Tags: reactjs, redux, global-variables, action, store

store file get default value when make routing using this code:
window.location.replace("/home");

i have login page in my website and when user enter data successfully i get user information from API ,, and then i want to save user information to my store and i'm did it then go to home page and when open Home page the store file get default value

//NOTE : THIS SUBCODE.

onLoginClickHandler = () => {
    var self = this;

```
    query.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      // AXIOS
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/user/get_user',
        params: { uid: user.uid },

      }).then(function (response) {

        self.setState({
          FirstName: response.data.FirstName,
          LastName: response.data.LastName,
          phone: response.data.Phone,
          Birthday: response.data.Birthday,
          Gender: response.data.Gender,
          Country: response.data.Country,
          number: snapshot.val().number,
          src: response.data.src,
        })

        self.props.userDataAction(
          response.data.FirstName,
          response.data.LastName,
          response.data.Phone)
    //-- THIS ( userDataAction ) IS FUNCTION TO RESET STORE VALUE --

       window.location.replace("/home");


    //------------ THIS.TO.MACK.ROUTING FROM LOGIN TO HOME ---------


      }).catch(function (err) {
        NotificationManager.error('Sorry Try Agin');
      })

    }, function (error) {
      NotificationManager.error('Your Email Or Password Incorrect');
    });
  } else {
    NotificationManager.error('Not varify yet!', 'Error', 10000);

}).catch(function (error) {
  NotificationManager.error('Your Email Or Password Incorrect');
});
```

}

LOGICAL ERROR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use localStorage to keep your data intact.

```
localStorage.setItem("mydata", {"myname": "abc"});
```

You can fetch the data through localStorage using getItem function as given below:

```
localStorage.getItem("mydata");
```

And data can be removed from localStorage using removeItem function as given below:

```
localStorage.removeItem("mydata");
```

You can also avoid reloading the app by using e.g. window.history.pushState() and that won't reset the store data.

Comment: I can using it in all of classes im my system?

Comment: @MustafaAlsalhi you could optimize your performance by reading from local storage on start up and only write to it when the user logs out. And also pls mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i need anther routing method alternative of  window.location.replace work with onClick() and not make refresh the page